# iPhone Capabilities for Codeception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, codeception, browserstack

Can any one please suggest, how to define iphone or ipad capabilities in Codeception yml file using Browserstack.

I have tried on it through the below script yml.

```
config:
WebDriver:
  url: 'http://www.google.com'
  host: 'hub.browserstack.com'
  port: 80
  browser: iphone
  capabilities:
    'browserstack.user': '<username>'
    'browserstack.key' : '<automate-key>'
    'device': 'iPhone 5'
    'platform': 'MAC'
```

Following error message is displaying in Command line.

```
 [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException]
  There was an error. Please try again.
```